# Properties of two connected star graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

Define $S_n$ to be a star graph with $n$ vertices. Assume you have two star graphs, $S_m$ and $S_k$ where $m,k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Pick one random vertex from each graph and connect them with an edge. What is a property of the resulting graph $G$?

1. Max-degree($G$) = max($k$, $m$) + 1
2. Max-degree($G$) = max($k$, $m$)
3. $G$ is two-colorable
4. $G$ has a chromatic number of 3

I drew two star graphs, each with two vertices coming out from the core vertex. By connecting the graphs in different ways, I ruled out #1 and #2, because sometimes the formula is consistent with #1 and the other times the formula is consistent with #2.

Also, I'm pretty sure $G$ cannot be two-colorable because you can connect both graphs in at least one way such that two vertices are the same color and are connected.

Therefore, I'm left with the last option, that $G$ has a chromatic number of 3. So far, I'm able to connect the graph in different ways and maintain 3 colors. I believe this is the answer, but I'm not certain.

I'm wondering if my thought process here is correct. Also, if there is a more formal way of determining the properties of these two connected star graphs, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Any graph without cycles is two colorable.

You made a mistake when you eliminated 3.: you assumed that the two stars are already two-colored, and then connected them so that the edge connects the same colors [ but in this case you can re-color one of the stars the opposite way]. But two colorable means the final graph should be two colored, which is always possible

Comment: Ah - I missed that! Thank you!